# How to handle getting a list of unique customers per product grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I am using SQL server 2012.

I've been asked to provide a breakdown of customers by product groupings.
Eg How many customers have **only** got products & subproducts set A.

How many customers have **only** got products & subproducts set A and B.

How many customers have **only** got products & subproducts set B and C.

I am trying to figure out the best way to solve this problem. I have a table like this:

```
|CustomerKey|  ProductCode |SubProductCode|
|-----------|--------------|--------------|
| ABC123    | PROD1        | SP1          |
| ABC123    | PROD1        | SP2          |
| ABC145    | PROD1        | SP1          |
| ABC157    | PROD3        | SP1          | 
| ABC157    | PROD2        | SP5          |
| ABC157    | PROD1        | SP2          |
```

I wish to categorise my customers using ProductCode and SubProductCode like this:

```
|ProductCode | SubProductCode|Category|
|------------|---------------|--------|
| PROD1      |SP1            | A      |
| PROD1      |SP2            | B      |
| PROD2      |SP5            | C      |
| PROD3      |SP1            | D      |
```

The output I want to see is like this:

```
|Category| Number of customers with ONLY this|
|--------|-----------------------------------|
| A      |    1 (ABC145)                     |
| B      |    0                              |
| A & B  |    1 (ABC123)                     |
| C      |    0                              |
| B,C & D|    1 (ABC157)                     |
```

Note how we did not count customer ABC123 in category A because this customer has both an A & B category product.  Similarly, although customer ABC157 has PROD2 and SP5 (category C), this customer is not included in that count because they ALSO have other category products.

I don't want to waste hours on this only to realise I was going down the wrong path.  I have in mind to create a pivot table of all customers with a count per Product & SubProduct.  Something like this:

```
|CustomerKey |PROD1 SP1 |PROD1 SP2|PROD2 SP5 |PROD3 SP1|
|------------|----------|---------|----------|---------|
|ABC123      | 1        | 1       |  0       |  0      |
|ABC145      | 1        | 0       |  0       |  0      |
|ABC157      | 0        | 1       |  1       |  1      |
```

I would then be able to do a count of the fields.  This approach has the added benefit of allowing me to redefine what makes Category A at some point in the future and I simply adjust which columns I count.

My question is what is the best way to achieve my objective?  Is there a better way to do this? I am going to be writing about 150 case statements for the various product and subproduct combinations that exist!

Comment: I can't figure out what you really want.  You have to different formats that you are specifying, and they are not the same.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 doesn't really offer something magical to do this, so you might better write it as a series of case statements (pivot doesn't do something for performance wise and you still need to write too many code). In either case, pivot or multiple case statements, you can write that as you write a dynamic pivot.